# Is there any way to find out where the APK file downloaded from?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, apk

I have to make my apk downloaded from several websites (not the google store)
and make them works with their own server url.

At first I was going to use webbrowser's cookie to store informations
but it failed giving me the knowledge that the cookies are not shared with different apps.

thought about making a temporary file to store informations the intalled app would use but
maybe that won't be welcomed by the players.

In fact, I don't think it's possible but I heard
that there ARE many developers who already done this. (No evidence at all btw)

As so, I want to borrow your kind ideas or solutions.
Thx

Comment: Are you saying that you want to track where users obtained your application?

Comment: Yes, so as my app may use the information to choose proper server url or something like that.

Comment: Can't you just distribute a site-specific APK?

Comment: I'd want to. But my superior wants it to be done. (sigh)
Well thx anyway. I'm trying to persuade him.

Comment: What if someone downloads the APK on their computer and transfers it with a USB? The ***only*** solution that makes sense here is site-specific APKs.